# Combustion of thiazole

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, combustion, heterocyclic-compounds

I am learning Chemistry from a book Heterocyclic compounds and I have bumped onto a following image with given tasks:

*[image]*

What is the balanced reaction?
What is the RMM of thiazole?
What is the fuel-air mass ratio?
What is the oxygen depletion?
What is the yield of CO2?
What is the yield of H2O?
What is the yield of N2?
For ideal combustion, what is the yield of carbon-monoxide?

Now, from this I can see that aformentioned product is Thiazole( checked on wiki ) and that products of combustion are carbon dioxide, water, hydrogen sulphide (H2S) and nitrogen. Now how can I solve this matter having in mind following data that air is consisted of 21% O2 and 79% of N2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I have to ask about the premise of your question- why are you teaching yourself chemistry from a book on heterocyclic compounds?  The rest of your question suggests you've skipped the basics and jumped to fairly advanced stuff.  There are many good introductory chemistry that will walk you through problems similar to this one that will be a far easier starting point than heterocyclic compounds.

Assuming your general question is "how do I do calculations on oxidation reactions?", you fill find whole chapters and even books on the topic.  I would highly recommend starting with something like "What is the balanced reaction of combusting propane (C3H8) in pure oxygen?"  You will need this kind of basis to be able to work up problems like the one you ask about with many possible products and spectator species.

This will get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combustion#Chemical_equations with answer to the first question.  In general though, pick up a used introduction to chemistry book up off Amazon for $10 and start with those walk throughs.

Hope this helps answer your real question and please let me know if I misunderstood and you had a more specific question about this particular problem.

EDIT: For the yield questions, you can use the the balanced equation and molecular weights to come up with a yield.

You'll have something like:
$$yield=stoichiometricRatio*\frac{MW_{product}}{MW_{thiazole}}$$

$$\frac{g_{product}}{g_{thiozole}}=\frac{mol_{product}}{mol_{thiozole}}*\frac{g_{product}}{mol_{product}}*\frac{mol_{thiazole}}{g_{thiazole}}$$

If they give you a mass (or mass flow rate) of thiazole, you could further convert this to a mass (or mass flow rate) of products.

Comment: You have a valid point. I have answered on all Q. except on the following ones:5,6,7. I just don't know how to find out yield of some compound?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a more detailed explanation of calculating yields.  The question is a little vague on what it is looking for but this is how I would interpret it.